# Issue with display textview Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with my project I have a long text which goes off screen and I need a scrollable I fixed that however now my text goes off screen to the right it doesn't stay all compact in anyone have any suggestions? I want my text to be in and fully visible as well as having a scroll since its a lot. Also I could force orientation however I don't want to do that since the design will look bad. I tried a few solutions but there is no hope.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/abouthusky"
            android:id="@+id/abouthusky"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the image of how it looks like:
http://i57.tinypic.com/2qt8hvm.png

Here is the Fragment code:

```
public class Fragment_list_1 extends android.app.Fragment {
    View rootview;  
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout_1, container, false);
        return rootview;

    }
}
```

Also I know I asked this in the past but I messed up on the question and did not provide enough detail.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a </RelativeLayout> at the end of the code it just that it dosent include it.

Comment: Did you tried this, no need of scrollview..

In Xml:
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"

Then use:

yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your xml to this::

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abouthusky"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:maxLines="25"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/abouthusky" />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in code :

```
  yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

do this.It should work

Comment: You just saved me my project thank you so much it worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
            `textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`
to enable scrolling in the Text View, instead of using Scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abouthusky"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="@string/abouthusky" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It sort off worked but there is still a little text on the outside.